# How to reset ASP.Net sessions state timeout with ajax request

Tags: asp.net, ajax, session-state, session-timeout

I am working on an ASP.Net Full-Ajax site. Because all operations have doing by Ajax requests, any postback request will not send to server.In other hand I have a javascript timer that send an ajax request to check sessions and if it expired redirect user to login page.

Problem is here: When user is working on page for 20 minutes and all operations will do with ajax requests after 20 minutes its session expired and user will redirect to login page (by that javascript timer) exactly during working with page. So I need to refresh its session state with ajax request. But how ?How can I do that to reset sessions state timeout by an ajax request!?!!

Depend on my Google search results, I can not be preform by ajax request because SessionId store in client as a cookie and to update it need to preform a post back request :(

**Note** : Session state is set on `InProc` mode with `timeout = 20`

Sorry about my bad English syntax, I am new in English

Regards, Foroughi

**UPDATE** : Does an ajax request update sessions state timeout?!!

**UPDATE** : When my user login to site I set a session like this :

```
Session["UserId"] = UserObject.Id;
```

and in all my page I use some web method to preform operation like this :

```
[WebMethod]
public static Opr1 (Paramethers...)
{

   //Question is here , how can i update UserId  session to prevent to expire,how can i update it

   //execute my codes to preform Opr1

}
```

Comment: There shouldn't be a problem in the way you describe it. Ajax requests are going to the server. When the server executes some code (in fact, when it just gets a request), it slides the session to another 20 minutes.

Comment: i dont think so Ofer, because my ajax request do not update sessions timeout ? what is wrong here ?! :(

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431733/keeping-asp-net-session-open-alive

Comment: The Ajax request doesn't need to update anything with regards to session. It just need to get to the server. Does it get to the server? Check with breakpoints if you can.

Comment: @ShoaibShaikh, it's not the same issue.

Comment: @ShoaibShaikh , i do not want to keep it alive, i want to check its status , there is no duplicate question, i checked them all in SO

Comment: @OferZelig, so you think ajax request will update sessions states timeout? yes?!!

Comment: Yes - every request extends the session.

Comment: sorry i wasn't very specific.. let me post an answer so that it could be helpful to others

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using WebMethods you should decorate your methods like

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
```

Further if you need to keep your session alive you should try create an HTTPHandler that implements IRequireSessionState this interface allows to get/set(deserialize/serialize) the session variables that will eventually slide session timeout.

This is a good article about the sessions and ajax calls.

http://seejoelprogram.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/maintaining-aspnet-session-state-in-an-ajax-application/

Hope this will be helpful

Regards.

Comment: I have the same problem when ajax call, but I'm using MVC and I call my action from client ( my action returns json data).

is there any similar solution for actions in mvc ?

Answer (score 0):

this is the way I am doing:

I have a simple web service to check if user is authenticated, but you can change the code to check if session is not expired.

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" Class="CheckAutheticated" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;

[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]

[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class CheckAutheticated  : System.Web.Services.WebService {

[WebMethod]
public string checkAuthenticated()
{
    return "authenticated";
}
```

}

then client side I call it:

```
function checkAuthenticated() {
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "CheckAutheticated.asmx/checkAuthenticated",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: checkAuthenticatedOk,
                error: checkAuthenticatedError
            });
        }
    }
    function checkAuthenticatedOk() { }
    function checkAuthenticatedError() {
        $("#sessionExpiredCover").show();
    }
```

here some basic css

```
<style type="text/css">
    #sessionExpiredCover {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100000;
    display: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    /*opacity: .7;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(opacity=.7);*/
    }
    </style>
```

and finally the div

```
    <div id="sessionExpiredCover">
    <div style="background-color:#fff; margin:100px; height:200px; width:400px;"><h1>Session expired</h1>
        <br />
        <asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="~/Login.aspx" runat="server" Text="Please log in again" />
    </div>
    </div>
```