# jquery c# webmethod

Tags: c#, jquery, webmethod

I have an application where I am making a call to a webmethod from Js.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "mypage.aspx/MyWebMethod",
    ....
    ....
    });
```

In my C# webmethod I have set

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
```

The problem is very strange and I donot even know if it is a Jquery or C#
or server setting problem.

Problem: 
When I run the webpage and start using the application, everything working fine.
However, if I just keep the webpage open (for something like 5 min) 
and donot do anything with it..and then try to use the application, the ajax call fails.

Can someone please let me know what the problem could be?

Comment: Ok, try this: Start the server (F5), and do your ajax call. Then wait 5 minutes, or however long it took for it to stop working, and then try opening a page on your server, and see if it loads. Then, without refreshing your first page, do the ajax call, and see if it works.

Comment: you're using a webmethode with EnableSession=true and your session might been expired after 5 min for that reason your ajax call fails consider making the expiry date of your session more longer

Comment: @Sora ... how do I make the session last longer..?

Comment: change the expiry date in your web.config file do some search in google :)

Comment: The problem was with the session variables which are being wiped off every 10 min or so..I couldnot set the time to higher value even through global.asax...therefore I stored the session variable which was not very sensitive in a hidden variable and used it..

Answer (score 1):

I **strongly** recommend you change this:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
```

To this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session
```

That way you don't need to use `(EnableSession = true)`
I tested my own and there is no problem

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Its likely that the ASP Session is expiring, and you are getting an HTTP 401 or similar.

You can either handle the in your ajax `error{}` callback, or alternatively consider [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431733/keeping-asp-net-session-open-alive) [workarounds](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13945/Make-session-last-forever) for keeping the session alive in the background.