# asp net refreshing authentication token without full postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, forms-authentication

I have a ASP.net Page that requires Authentication using the standard .net membership provider. On this page there is a third party text editor that run in an iframe.
The problem is I cannot check on the client side if the user is using the text editor. If the user spend to too long on the text editor the the authentication Token will time out and user will be logged OUT when he click the page "process" button.

How Can I Refresh my authentication token without disturbing user? ( no postback)

I can have javascript sending something every 15min but how and what?

Comment: you need to use a handler and jquery. see here for details http://stackoverflow.com/a/1431789/823161

Comment: Yes that was a good answer this seams to be working for me. thanks