# I wanted to create a new session, once current servlet session got expired.

Tags: servlets, session-timeout, servlet-container

i have to avoid the following condition. 
 I'm running the servlet . This session will be expired in Browser after my Time-Out (WEB.XML) period. After getting this time-out, i need to reload this link in Browser to activate this servlet. I don't want to reload the link again, it should be create a new session after the Time-Out.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution would be extending the *time-out* (`session-timeout`) in `web.xml`.

Your client, JS application in browser should connect to server to announce that it is still live.

Comment: instead of increasing timeout. i want to do the auto refresh over a program by calling dopost/doget  again. if i need to add the dopost/doget, where do i need to add ? at which portion it has to call again ( to create new Session)

Comment: I think this is impossible. Your client (browser) should handle this case, no server.

Answer (score 0):

The timeout is the period of inactivity before the session is killed off by the server. If you want to keep the session alive - even when there is no activity - then you could extend the inactivity timeout.

Alternatively you could write a Javascript AJAX keepalive that sends a heartbeat to the server every few minutes. You could write a simple dedicated servlet to receive this keepalive and send back a simple response. The heartbeat would count as activity - and thus keep the session alive.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431733/keeping-asp-net-session-open-alive) gives an example of the Javascript (the question is C# related but that shouldn't matter).