# Automatically keep the asp.net session alive

Tags: asp.net

I want to keep the session alive until the user sign out in asp website.

I used the following code in webconfig:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20" />
```

if the user is in idle state for 20 min the session ll be timeout.

but I want to extends the session timeout before the session going to end.

I need to keep the session is alive.

Comment: Use ajax to keep session alive.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431733/keeping-asp-net-session-open-alive

Comment: i tried that one but Is not working

Comment: any error or problem?

Comment: .ashx page is not executed. And the session ill be time out as per webcongfing time out