# The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading , if we use F5 load balancer to access asp.net pages

Tags: asp.net, session, load-balancing, session-state, f5

i deployed asp.net application in two asp.net servers and  users access this application through F5 Load balance.
here we facing issue when user was idle on asp.net page for 10 min , and after when user click the button on page, and page  can not be displayed message appers in IE,

and in firefox  below message
 The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.
In IIS default session timeout value is 20 Min

In F5 TcpIP time out value :10 Min

Comment: The key here is whether the session timer is tied to any tcp idle timeouts. I'd think no, and if that is the case that's better, as a 20 minute timer at tcp level would open you to port exhaustion in even a mild DDoS event.

Have you taken a tcpdump to see if the client is doing a new handshake after those 10 minutes or if it's just acking on an existing tcp session?

Answer (score 0):

If the MachineKeys in the config on both servers are identical, upping the timeout to 20 minutes should work. If that doesn't work, or you don't have the rights to do so, you'll need a keep-alive in your asp.net application [like in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431733/keeping-asp-net-session-open-alive)

Comment: when page post back after 7 Min and after we wait more than 3 minuts and do post back again , session not reset and page can not be displayed message appears in IE