# Session does not stay alive

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, state-management

I am using the following article to keep my session alive in my asp.net application.

[How to Keep Session Alive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431733/keeping-asp-net-session-open-alive)

But when I checked the session variable value using alert in javascript I didn't find anything. `alert('<%=Session["Heartbeat"]%>');`

Actually In my webpage there is no postback. All the work I am doing from Jquery Ajax. When there is any postback only then the solution of that article works.
But I want to keep my session alive without any postback.

Please help guys.....

Comment: Please can anyone help  me ?

Comment: you dont need post back. just create a webservice and call that web service from your front end using jquery. make sure that you allow your webservice to access session by putting [WebMethod(EnableSession=true)] on your function and then proceed to do what is said on your link

Comment: Hi @Mysterio11 I tried your idea but it's still not showing anything when I am checking it through alert in javascript.

Comment: Is this ASP.Net Web Form or ASP.Net MVC?

Answer (score 1):

`alert('<%=Session["Heartbeat"]%>');` will not work without fully postback, because `<%=Session["Heartbeat"]%>` is a server-side code.

In order for Session to keep alive, all you need is just a simple Ajax call to server.

Easiest way to implement ASHX generic handler, and call it via Ajax. For example,

### Ping.ashx

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" CodeBehind="Ping.ashx.cs" Class="PROJECT_NAMESPACE.Ping" %>
```

### Ping.ashx.cs

```
public class Ping : IHttpHandler
{ 
   public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   {
      context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
      context.Response.Write("Ping");
   }

   public bool IsReusable { get { return false; }}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this [example](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15793.keep-session-alive-in-asp-net-application.aspx) :-

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function KeepSession() {
    // A request to server
    $.post("http://servername:port/appName/SessionCheck.aspx");

    //now schedule this process to happen in some time interval, in this example its 1 min
    setInterval(KeepSession, 60000);
}

    // First time call of function
    KeepSession(); 
 </script>
```

Comment: but it's still not showing anything when I am checking it through alert in javascript.