# How to keep session variables updated always in ASP. NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session-timeout

After login I keep some user info in `Session[""]` vars.

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }

            try
            {
                var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

                switch (result)
                {
                    case SignInStatus.Success:
                        var user = User.Identity;
                        try
                        {
                            ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();

                            var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));

                            string userId = UserManager.FindByName(model.UserName)?.Id;

                            var s = UserManager.GetRoles(userId);

                            var u = db.UsersViews.First(x => x.Id == userId);

                            Session["UserFullName"] = u.LastName + " " + u.FirstName.Substring(0, 1) + ". " + u.MiddleName.Substring(0, 1) + ".";
                            Session["UserRole"] =  u.RoleName;

                            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            return View("Lockout");
                        }
                    case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                        return View("Lockout");
                    case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                        return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                    case SignInStatus.Failure:
                    default:
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                        return View(model);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Later I use it like

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity

@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 " style="margin-left:2em; margin-right:0em;">
            <label class="form-control-sm mr-sm-2">@Session["UserFullName"] (@Session["UserRole"]) </label>
            <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm my-2 my-sm-0">Выход</a>
        </div>
    }
}
else
{
    <form class="navbar-right">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a id="loginLink" href="@Url.Content("~/Account/Login")" class="nav-link"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Вход</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
}
```

But once session gone there is no value to display.

**So my question is how to keep updated session vars without increaseing session timeout?**

Thank you!

Comment: If the session has timed out, the session variables are gone, by definition. So the question is kind of nonsensical, no offense. Are you asking how to persist data between sessions?

Comment: @JohnWu It seems like you are right. Any clue then?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431733/keeping-asp-net-session-open-alive

Comment: OP, my question points out a problem with the requirement that you have stated. I cannot advise you on requirements, only the solution. Can you come up with a different requirement that meets your needs? I already suggested one: Perhaps your actual requirement is to persist certain data *between* sessions.

Comment: Do you actually just want to logout the user after the regular session timeout period, but keep their session info alive?  You could do that by increasing session timeout but auto-logging the user out.  Also is it coincidence that @WillyDavidJr's link has a comment you wrote 2 years ago about this subject!

Comment: Have you noticed that you don't use var s? I think you meant Session["UserRole"] =  s.RoleName;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer here [ASP.NET MVC - Set custom IIdentity or IPrincipal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064271/asp-net-mvc-set-custom-iidentity-or-iprincipal)

But I adjusted this approach a little bit.

Here is my working code.

**Create few classes of `IPrincipal`**

```
 interface ICustomPrincipal : IPrincipal
    {
        string Id { get; set; }

        string FirstName { get; set; }
        string LastName { get; set; }
        string MiddleName { get; set; }

        string RoleName { get; set; }
    }

 public class CustomPrincipal : ICustomPrincipal
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string RoleName { get; set; }

        private string[] _roles; // Keep here English name of roles that ypu will use for Controller    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, Guest")]

        public IIdentity Identity { get; private set; }

        public bool IsInRole(string role)
        {
            return Array.BinarySearch(_roles, role) >= 0 ? true : false;
        }

        public CustomPrincipal(IIdentity identity, string[] roles)
        {
            Identity = identity;

            _roles = new string[roles.Length];

            roles.CopyTo(_roles, 0);

            Array.Sort(_roles);
        }
    }

 public class CustomPrincipalSerializeModel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
        public string RoleNameCode { get; set; } // English name of role like 'Administrator'
    }
```

**In Global.asax add**

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

           // Add this
            PostAuthenticateRequest += Application_PostAuthenticateRequest;
        }



  protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                //Do stuff here
                HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

                if (authCookie != null)
                {
                    FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

                    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

                    var serializeModel = serializer.Deserialize<CustomPrincipalSerializeModel>(authTicket.UserData);

                    var roles = new List<string>() { serializeModel.RoleNameCode }; // English name of role like 'Administrator'

                    var newUser = new CustomPrincipal(User.Identity, roles.ToArray())
                    {
                        Id = serializeModel.Id,
                        FirstName = serializeModel.FirstName,
                        LastName = serializeModel.LastName,
                        MiddleName = serializeModel.MiddleName,
                        RoleName = serializeModel.RoleName // Custom name of role i.e. in Spanish I use it to display for user
                    };


                      HttpContext.Current.User = newUser;
                }
            }


        }
```

**Your login method should get extra user data and keep in cookies**

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }

            try
            {
                var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

                switch (result)
                {
                    case SignInStatus.Success:

                        var user = User.Identity;
                        try
                        {
                            ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();

                            var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));

                            string userId = UserManager.FindByName(model.UserName)?.Id;

                            var s = UserManager.GetRoles(userId);
                             // db is EF context and UsersViews is user SQL View
                            var u = db.UsersViews.First(x => x.Id == userId);

                            var serializeModel = new CustomPrincipalSerializeModel
                            {
                                Id = u.Id,
                                FirstName = u.FirstName,
                                LastName = u.LastName,
                                MiddleName = u.MiddleName,
                                RoleName = u.RoleName,
                                RoleNameCode = u.RoleNameCode
                            };
                            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                            string userData = serializer.Serialize(serializeModel);
                            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, model.UserName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20), false, userData);
                            string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
                            HttpCookie faCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);
                            Response.Cookies.Add(faCookie);

                            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {

                            return View("Lockout");
                        }
                    case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                        return View("Lockout");
                    case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                        return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                    case SignInStatus.Failure:
                    default:
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                        return View(model);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }

        }
```

**And in your partial view like in my case in `_LoginPartial.cshtml`**

```
@* here put path where you keep CustomPrincipal class *@
@using GJob.Models.Views  

@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 " style="margin-left:2em; margin-right:0em;">
            <label class="form-control-sm mr-sm-2">@User.Identity.Name, @( (User as CustomPrincipal).LastName ) @( (User as CustomPrincipal).FirstName )  @( (User as CustomPrincipal).MiddleName ), @( (User as CustomPrincipal).RoleName )</label>
            <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm my-2 my-sm-0">Выход</a>
        </div>
    }
}
else
{
    <form class="navbar-right">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a id="loginLink" href="@Url.Content("~/Account/Login")" class="nav-link"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Вход</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
}
```